# How to output the exact number of letter in each result? Unscambler words

Tags: php, text, output, words

I have a working code for letter unscrambler. But I wanted to improve its output. I hope somebody can help me with this code.

When I enter the word "TEST", it will output the following:

Eses Sees Sets Sett Stet Tees Test Tets

How to not allow repeats of letters in its result?  The word "Sees and Tees should not be included.

Heres the code I am using.

```
function GetScrabbleWords($targetWord) 
{
        $targetArray=str_split($targetWord);
        $wordFileArray=array(3=>'data/threeletters.txt',4=>'data/fourletters.txt',5=>'data/fiveletters.txt',6=>'data/sixletters.txt',7=>'data/sevenletters.txt');
        foreach($wordFileArray as $fileWordLength=>$wordFile)
        {
                $wordFile=file($wordFile);
                sort($wordFile);
                foreach($wordFile as $word)
                {
                        $word=trim($word);
                        $wordArray=str_split($word);
                        $diffArray=array_diff($wordArray,$targetArray);
                        if (count($diffArray)==0) $scrabbleArray[$fileWordLength][$word]=$word;
                }
        }
        if ( !empty($scrabbleArray)) {      
        unset($scrabbleArray[7][$targetWord]);
        return $scrabbleArray;                              
        }
}                                               
$target=Input::get('formvar');
$targetWord=Str::upper($target);                                                

$my_values = array(GetScrabbleWords($targetWord));
echo $my_values;
```

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: I hope not to allow repeats of letters in its result? I hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is modified version of [Finding All Permutations of an Array](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_26.htm) function from PHP Cookbook. I hope this is what you're looking for, and `!preg_match( '/(\w)\1+/', $perms )` is the part where is the check for more than one repeated letter in permutation.

```
function pc_permute( $items, $perms = array( ), &$result = array() ) {
    if ( empty( $items ) ) {
        $perms = implode( $perms );
        if ( !in_array( $perms, $result ) && !preg_match( '/(\w)\1+/', $perms ) ) $result[] = $perms;
    } else {
        for ( $i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i ) {
            $newitems = $items;
            $newperms = $perms;
            list($foo) = array_splice( $newitems, $i, 1 );
            array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
            pc_permute( $newitems, $newperms, $result );
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$result = pc_permute( str_split( 'test' ) );

/*
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => etst
    [2] => tset
    [3] => stet
    [4] => tets
    [5] => tste
)
*/
```